# Removing whitespaces before and after specified character

Tags: perl, removing-whitespace

```
LIST.txt
ark = 1  bark= 2  car  =3  dorm    =4
ark=8  bark  = 25  car  =  33  dorm  =5
```

I have a file named LIST.txt as shown above. I want the ouput to be like shown in OUTPUT.txt

```
OUTPUT.txt
ark=1  bark=2  car=3  dorm=4
ark=8  bark=25  car=33  dorm=5
```

I was not succesful in removing the spaces before and after the "=". The method i tried to remove the whitespaces yielded me something like this

```
ark=1bark=2car=3dorm=4
ark=8bark=25car=33dorm=5
```

Can anyone help me out with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/\s*=\s*/=/g' LIST.txt
```

outputs

```
ark=1  bark=2  car=3  dorm=4
ark=8  bark=25  car=33  dorm=5
```